# Convert to JSON object in laravel framework

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, laravel-5

I get this

```
{"obj":"{\"name\":\"john welson\",\"age\":\"28\"}"}
```

how can convert it to JSON format to work with it easily?

When I use `json_decode($json)`, I get this error:

> "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".

This is what I want to do:

```
$post = new post;
$post->post = $Mydata['obj']['name'] ;
$post->save();
```

it is saving the name in the post table.

Answer (score 0):

Your escapes were a bit off, try this.

```
json_decode("{\"obj\":{\"name\":\"john welson\",\"age\":\"28\"}}");
```

Comment: thank you it is solved by json_decode with little bit change

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:**

the information being sent would be an object like this: 
{ **data**: JSON.stringfly(*the_object*) }

**Laravel controller:**

... (Request $request)
{
  $data = json_decode($request->**data**, true);
  ...
}